# Editing a single field for a model in its show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working to update a value for an item in its show view, so I have embedded a form with a submit button, in the view, however I have a second button at the bottom of the page which carries out a different action and reloads the page. I would like to have one button to both reload the page and update the value for the item at the same time; as opposed to needing to press two buttons. So far I haven't figured out how to do it.

the embedded form:

```
        <%= form_for @item, :url => { :action => "update" } do |f| %>
        <b>Amount to be Requested:<b>  
        <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
         <%= f.submit "Add" %>
        <% end %>
```

the button at the bottom of the page:

```
<p><%= button_to "Add to my Request", add_list_item_path(@item), :id => "add_button" %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand totally what you are doing, but from what i see, `items/update_requested` should handle your updating and then `redirect_to :back`.

I'd assume that this is the only form on  the page, and that second button isn't needed.

### EDIT

Based on the first comment you made I'd just point the form to an action that does both.

```
def update_and_unrelate
  @item = Item.find(params[:id]
  if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
    #do unrelated stuff here
  else
    redirect_to :back, :alert => "Didn't happen son"
  end
end
```

If you really want to improve the UI, just have one button and maybe do the unrelated if the field is filled out.

Personally I feel that the less buttons the better and just 'do' it for them is the best way.

Comment: Sorry for the long response time, here's the issue, I have the form submit button, which effectively submits the form, and then there is the second button which carries out a different, unrelated action. What I want to happen is have one button that both submits the form and carries out the other action.

Answer (score 0):

might not be exactly what you are looking for but will provide a better experience than refreshing the page:

https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place